how to hint inner select query to run parallel for bulk update
A SELECT query runs a "Parallel Seq" scan with a good number of workers. Now when this query is used as a subquery in an UPDATE it regresses to a "Seq" scan, i.e. non parallel.
A FOR loop or cursor will make this single commit instead of bulk, which again slows us down.
Hint: it has millions of records in select and updates millions of records, there is a groupby which cannot be joined in update query
Example of such inner query looks likes below
UPDATE user 
        SET user_type = select_user_type
FROM (
       SELECT id as select_id, array_agg(distinct(user_type)) as select_user_type FROM txn join meta using(id) group by id
     )
WHERE select_id = id;

What is the reason for that, and how can I improve it? The performance becomes extremely poor.
Edit 1: if not familiar then explain analyze in short look with only select

with same select query inside update

NOTE : Question is not about bulk update or not select query index, more on is there a way any update, insert or delete having an inner select query (select alone with group by, not DML) which can run in parallel_seq scan
Time consuming work around : Exported select query data to csv, then copy csv to temp_date(efficient and can track udpates) and then bulk updated the intended table

Could you please share the DDL for the tables and indexes involved, and the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this update statement? (it will be executed!)

I my not able share critical data, but make table as 20 million records in both the tables, from EXPLAIN I see only with select it has parallel_seq scan .. but adding the same as inner query to update it turns to seq scan, it between we are good with buffer hits.. allocated enough threads.. it is question of with updates how the optimizer can still choose parallel_seq scan for inner select query for bulk update

Hard to help without information. At least check your indexes because no query will magically be 300x faster just because of parallel scan. There is most likely something else going on, and the query plan might show it.

lets even assume it is 1x slower,  the problem in hand, is there a way in which we can still let optimizer detect this inner query for parallel_seq, to note it has become seq or parallel seq scan from index scan due to large data set in inner query

As temporary option now we are running select in IDE, export the data to CSV and COPY & UPDATE table in bulk, it is good we have right solution

Why did you use a subquery for this? There is no need for. I hope the query planner already changes your statement, but without having seen the query plan, I'm not sure. And did you index all the different id columns? And with many updates, you might want to lower the FILLFACTOR for the table you try to update.

hope above edit help more on problem statement

A bit of a shot in the dark but have you tried switching from the subquery to a materialized CTE? WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED(SELECT id as select_id, array_agg()..) UPDATE user SET user_type = select_user_type FROM cte WHERE select_id = id; The idea is that if it runs with the preferable plan when you run it on its own, maybe preventing the subquery from being merged into the outer query and forcing the db to evaluate it separately will get it to do the same, then feed its output to the final UPDATE

Any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement cannot use parallel query in PostgreSQL, so you will never get to have parallel processing for the subquery.
However, I am not sure if that is you problem. If you say it becomes 300 times slower, that can hardly be explained by the lack of parallelism. Very likely, the bottleneck is the UPDATE. You can verify that by looking at the result of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the statement.
I can give you a couple of ideas to boost your performance:

Check if there are triggers on the table that you UPDATE and if there are, try to make them as fast as possible.

Try not too have too many indexes on the table, because they slow down updates.

To get parallelization, you have to open several database connections and run several such UPDATE statements in parallel. You can add WHERE conditions to divide the load, e.g. WHERE id BETWEEN 100001 AND 200000 or WHERE id % 5 = 2.



This is one time activity so triggers, lets not worry on index and constraint or log, as the problem in question is along with update inner select query changes from parallel_seq to seq, as far as update we are looking to do bulk update to make it better..

That is a bulk update. You'll have to get more information to figure out why it is slow. Set track_io_timing = on and use EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).

edited with more info, ignoring buffers (data in each partition is in millions and vacuum and block size is efficient), hope this help us

No images. Formatted text, and don't edit it.
